# Is using "iff" appropriate?

Tags: mathematics, writing, writing-style

Is the word "iff", meaning "if and only if", recognized outside of logic?

In particular, is it appropriate for a physics text?  Or is this kind of abbreviation frowned upon?

Comment: Suggest that OP give more specifics about what kind of context is expected. Written on blackboard? Homework? Lecture notes? Thesis? Published paper? Spoken aloud? (In roughly decreasing order of acceptability.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; some answers, opinions, and amusing puns have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117839/discussion-on-question-by-student0284-is-using-iff-appropriate). Please review [this FAQ](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4230/why-do-the-moderators-move-comments-to-chat-and-how-should-i-behave-afterwards/4231#4231) before posting a comment below this one.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The abbreviation *iff* is generally understood in several fields outside logic, and in my experience it is well understood by physicists, but the golden rule is to define every abbreviation at its first use and/or provide a list of abbreviations. In this way, even those not familiar with an abbreviation will be able to understand the text.

However, in general, abbreviations may make a text less readable and therefore should be used judiciously. Thus, ask yourself if you will have to use the expression *if and only if* so frequently to warrant an abbreviation, sparing you just a bunch of characters, and think whether to limit its use to e.g. theorem statements.

Comment: I don't agree that defining iff as an abbreviation is correct, at least in maths.

Comment: @JessicaB By common definition of [_abbreviation_](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abbreviation) —"a shortened form of a written word or phrase used in place of the whole word or phrase"—, I don't know why you wouldn't call it an abbreviation. Note also that the OP is interested in physics.

Comment: That's a very wide definition of abbreviation, and if you're using that definition then your rule isn't really correct. For example, you would never provide as explanation of it's. Note that iff doesn't follow any standard pattern for forming an abbreviation, and also cannot be spoken aloud in the contracted form (while retaining its meaning).

Comment: @JessicaB _It's_ is part of the English language, and it's a specific form of abbreviation: it's a _contraction_. And one can choose abbreviations outside standard patterns. The fact that it cannot be spoken aloud is irrelevant: it just means that it's not an _acronym_. But also within maths, I suspect that many would agree that that is an abbreviation. E.g., here is a quotation from H. B. Enderton, _Elements of Set Theory_: "Also we abbreviate the phrase "if and only if" as "iff"". So, I feel you may have a too personal view of the meaning of abbreviation.

Comment: @JessicaB I also add that _iff_ is present in the Oxford Dictionary of English and it is exactly defined as an abbreviation: "A written form of abbreviation of the phrase ‘if and only if’".

Comment: @JessicaB 'cannot be spoken aloud'  The Concise Oxford English Dictionary supplies a pronunciation guide for "iff" (in which it's pronounced exactly the same as "if").

Comment: @DanielHatton This could make for confusing discussions!

Comment: @user151413 Curiouser and curiouser: I was working from the 1995 edition of the (Concise) OED.  It looks like more recent editions have dropped the pronunciation guide for "iff", added the qualifiers "written" and "abbreviation" as quoted by Massimo, and added a (verifiably incorrect) date to the etymology,

Comment: @DanielHatton The full OED reports "if and only if" as pronunciation.

Comment: I don't agree with your "golden rule" of defining every abbreviation or providing a list. I think it would be unusual and unnecessary to explain "where cos denotes the cosine function, and arctan denotes the inverse of the tangent function, and exp denotes the exponential function, and max denotes the maximum function", and so on. The OP's question is whether (or in what context) "iff" falls into the quite large collection of notation that can reasonably be used without explanation.

Comment: @JamesMartin It all depends on context really. If you have an equation block then writing iff would be perfectly understandable but within a block of text it could be misunderstood.

Comment: @JamesMartin Everything should be read with a grain of common sense. Otherwise, in everyday communication, one can end up in an infinite regress for almost everything.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano Precisely. So the question is asking whether or not "iff" is like "exp". I genuinely don't see how the golden rule helps. There are some things one needs to explain, and some things (like "exp") one doesn't need to. And the OP is asking whether "iff" needs to be explained. In a maths context, I wouldn't think it does. If your answer is that "iff" is sufficiently non-standard in a physics context that it needs to be explained, then fine.  But covering that by a rule of "explain everything" doesn't seem to help.

Comment: @JamesMartin My answer says exactly what it says: that "iff" will _likely_ be understood in physics, but that if you apply the "golden rule" it will be _certainly_ understood, also by those who are not so familiar with the abbreviation. That's it, I really don't know what you're arguing about, but I can accept that you don't like it ;-)

Comment: @JamesMartin I actually would expect for a well-written and well-edited textbook to include a glossary or an introductory chapter that includes all those definitions, or at the very least a reference to another textbook that does.

Comment: I agree that the abbreviation should be defined, since this could be unintentionally be confused with "identification, friend or foe". Robot designers and military automation scientists may read the publication. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identification_friend_or_foe

Comment: @JessicaB what are the standard patterns for forming an abbreviation?

Answer (score 20):

You can sort this sort of thing out by looking at papers in journals.  Google speeds this along.  I searched as follows:

> "iff" journal die reine und angewandte mathematik

and

> "iff" "Physical review"

to confirm that there are plenty of papers in physics and math that use "iff" without explanation.  The one paper I saw that defined this was in Physical Review Letters.  You might want to search similarly in one of your target journals.

However:  Do think about your target audience.  An experimental physicist might be confused by this abbreviation.

A nice trick is to write things with nice large figures and few abbreviations and see how long the paper is.  If you are over the page limits for a journal by just a little, you start shrinking images, tightening the prose, and using the more common abbreviations.  Many physics papers have way too many abbreviations so do try to not use every abbreviation possible.

Another reason to use an abbreviation or a symbol (like `\Leftrightarrow`) is to make a multiline-equation a single-line equation, or to make a two-column equation fit in one column. This can greatly improve the look and readability of a paper.

Comment: Thank you for your research. Its only for a bachelors project I'm doing, not a paper. As the page count is not limited I think I will stick to the advice given not to use too many abbreviations.

Comment: @Student0284  For a bachelors project you probably will do fine either way.

Comment: The reason why this is defined in Physical Review Letters is very likely that Physical Review has a rather strict style guide which is usually rather strictly enforced.  Acronyms have to be defined, even if they are considered to be well-known.

Comment: This experimentalist would understand it, but probably picked up outside work from someone with a maths background.  I'd use it only if really necessary, e.g. in something like a display equation that's better without wrapping

Comment: I doubt that anyone can get a degree in physics without taking some math classes, where they will be exposed to proofs, thus getting exposed to "iff".

Comment: By the way, there is a latex command for if and only if symbol. It is `\iff`

Comment: @GuntramBlohm It is entirely possible to take those math classes in a language different from English though, in which case one might be exposed only to another shorthand for the same concept.

Comment: @user151413  "iff" isn't an acronym.  If it was, it would be "iaoi".

Comment: @Bloke I'm sure you got my point: Physical Review has rather strict rules about all kind of things, such as spelling out abbreviations, acronyms, and those kind of things - see also the other comments as to whether this counts as an abbreviation.  Also, I don't see why acronyms would only be based on first letters - acronyms for research proposals essentially never do this.

Comment: @Bloke The main issue with the 'iff' as a possible acronym is that it is not ever pronounced.   Thus NATO is an acronym and FBI is an abbreviation to most people as it is not generally pronounced as a word.  Of course many people get this wrong, even academics, just as they say PIN number or ORCID ID.

Comment: Many here are missing that I said "there are plenty of papers in physics and math that use 'iff' without explanation" and that includes papers in the Annals of Mathematics and Physical Review Letters.  I do not think Physical Review Letters minds at all it one uses it with or without explanation.

Comment: @user151413  The APS style guide says ``abbreviations should be defined the first time they are introduced in text'' not 'must' be used.  In practice, as author and referee, I have never before noticed this.  This is not at all strictly enforced.  Of course, I do complain as referee if a paper has uses to many abbreviations or fails to define the non-obvious abbreviations.

Comment: @TerryLoring My experience with the APS copyediting procedure is that in the preparation for that, the editor will spell out any abbreviation they don't overlook, or ask you to do so, including things completely canonical in the field.   Some APS journals provide redlined proofs, where you can very well spot that.

Comment: @user151413  I guess this proves that APS is a huge organization.  It could be that different editors have different attitudes.

Comment: @TerryLoring There's no doubt about the latter. But overall APS editors are much more picky about the rules than those of other journals.  (Just try writing "i.e." or "e.g." without surrounding commas, or use a double hyphen '--' rather than '---'.)

Answer (score 15):

The use of *iff* outside of formal logic is shorthand, and so is only appropriate in contexts where shorthand is appropriate.

For example, it's probably fine in a piece of maths homework, may or may not be a good choice in lecture notes (depending on their style), and not suitable for a research paper (at least in pure maths).

Comment: The word "iff" appears in the 1995 edition of the Concise Oxford English Dictionary.  The etymological note in there suggests it arose as an "extension" of "if", rather than as a "shorthand" or "abbreviation".

Comment: I don't know what is standard in physics. However, in mathematics (outside of logic), this is the correct answer. Though it might appear in published papers sometimes, it is standard (and usually considered better) to expand shorthand like "iff" to "if and only if," in much the same way that the backwards A and E symbols for "for all" and "there exist" may be okay in notes or homework, but are almost always written in words in more formal text.

Answer (score 3):

Same as for sine: "sine" in prose and "sin" in formulas.  Of course, for formulas, you may be better served by "⇔".  Depending on your intended audience, you may want to define whichever version you use before the first use.

Comment: In this case, I think it's more a matter of "sin" being another completely unrelated word.  You wouldn't use "tan", "cot" or "sec" in prose either for similar reasons.  The others ("cos", "csc") don't have that ambiguity issue, but are left with 3-letter abbreviations mostly for consistency I think.

Answer (score 0):

What type of physics text? A research paper? An introductory textbook? I'd say in general "iff" is fine to use in an educated setting *iff* material equivalence needs to be emphasized. Personally, I'd leave it out if not.